# jQuery validate across multiple fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have 3 input fields that ask for the number of people, and of them how many are adults and how many are children. I am trying to use jQuery validate plugin to add a custom method where
children + adults = number of people

This is my validation call

```
$("#form2").validate({
    errorElement: "span",
        rules: {
        attendees: {
             required: true,
             digits: true
        },              
        adults: {
             required: true,
             digits: true
        },              
        children: {
             required: true,
             digits: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        attendees: "Enter the number of persons (including yourself)", 
        adults: "Enter number of adults", 
        children: "Enter number of childern"                
    }               
});
```

I looked at the group feature and `.addMethod()` method of the validate plugin but it seems that it was crafted only with one element in mind. Any ideas?

Comment: You could throw it in a `.each()` statement maybe?

Comment: I would suggest, completely skip the attendees input if you want to put a restriction that total = adult + children. Instead, have a hidden field "total" the value for which should be updated to children + adult just before the form is submitted.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Follow [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) for creating a custom method/rule.  Here, I simply call it `totalCheck`, but you can name it anything you wish.

```
$.validator.addMethod('totalCheck', function(value, element, params) {
    var field_1 = $('input[name="' + params[0] + '"]').val(),
        field_2 = $('input[name="' + params[1] + '"]').val();
    return parseInt(value) === parseInt(field_1) + parseInt(field_2);
}, "Enter the number of persons (including yourself)");
```

It's implemented just like any other rule.  The two parameters are the `name` attributes of the two other fields you want to check against.  Since this new rule says the field must contain the sum of the two other fields, the `required` and `digits` rules are now redundant and can be removed.

```
$("#form2").validate({
    errorElement: "span",
    rules: {
        attendees: {
            totalCheck: ['adults', 'children'] // <-- your custom rule
        },
        adults: {
            required: true,
            digits: true
        },
        children: {
            required: true,
            digits: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        adults: "Enter number of adults",
        children: "Enter number of childern"
    }
});
```

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/hBXL6/

---

**EDIT**:

Added a `keyup focusout` handler to re-validate `attendees` whenever other fields are changed.  These are the same two default event handlers used by the plugin.

```
$('input[name="adults"], input[name="children"]').on('keyup focusout', function() {
    $('input[name="attendees"]').valid();
});
```

**New working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/ua0534dv/2/

Comment: is there some parameters limit for this?

Comment: @Limon, no limit on the number of parameters that I am aware.

Comment: @user2956826 is right - changing adults/children fields does not re-validate attendees.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Sparky is not complete: the `adults` and `children` need to re-validate `attendees` when changed.

Append this at the end:

```
$('input[name=adults],input[name=children]').on('change', function(){
  $('input[name=attendees]').removeData("previousValue").valid();
});
```

Comment: I incorporated your idea into my answer.  No need for `removeData()` since nothing in this code has been set with `.data()`; and should be `keyup` and `focusout` so you get dynamic validation just like the plugin's defaults.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested in comments this is not a good practice. Nonetheless, if you still want to do it:

```
$("#form2").validate({
    errorElement: "span",
        rules: {
        attendees: {
             equal: $("#form2 #adults").val() + $("#form2 #children").val();
        },              
        adults: {
             required: true,
             digits: true
        },              
        children: {
             required: true,
             digits: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        attendees: "Enter the number of persons (including yourself)", 
        adults: "Enter number of adults", 
        children: "Enter number of childern"                
    }               
});
```

Comment: There is no such method or rule called `equal`.